# Do I have to learn Dart before starting learning Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been reading recently about a new technology called Google Flutter, which is used to develop mobile apps(Android/iOS) with a programming language called Dart.

All that being said, do I have to learn Dart as a strong prerequisite to build apps with flutter(which makes sense) or I will learn Dart by applying and using flutter components(I kinda learned React and it's conventions plus semantics by developing React Native applications so is it the same story here?).

Comment: This seems kind of opinion-based, but I would say as long as you are familiar with programming concepts (especially with a C-like language) then you should be fine jumping into Flutter without an exclusive focus on Dart beforehand.

Comment: Well, I come from Java and Go backgrounds, I wouldn't say it looks like Go, however it looks like Java especially with all those OOP conventions and annotations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Do I have to learn Dart before starting learning Flutter?

No.
Dart is easy and purposefully similar to java/JS/c#. If you know one of these, you won't be lost here.

As for flutter's widgets, it's quite similar to React but easier.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a C# dev, and I got up and running pretty quickly.

To me, it seems like a C# with somewhat less ceremony when building stuff, but it feels very, *very* similar.

Comment: Yeah kinda of, I would say it seems OOP more or less, due to the languages semantics and conventions.

Answer (score 3):

Really Not,Dart is such a simple and easy language that it inherits almost everything fron java and Js,If you know only one of them then you are ready to rock with flutter.

Me and almost all Flutter developer learnt Flutter first and Dart subsequently and automatically without informing themselves. And trust me the language doesnt matter, if you have hold on any language except speaking one,then you are gonna change your World.
Flutter is that awesome, and thats why we love Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to, If you don't know any other programming languages like C, Kotlin. If you already have experience in, you may start flutter. But Dart programing language is mandatory.
Go throw the official document for better understanding.
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer does not seem to provide more information than the accepted answer. Please enrich it with more details or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Without learning Dart don't move to flutter If you have some programming experince then it will be easy to learn dart and after that you can move in flutter.

Answer (score -2):

Must be before Flutter
Learn darts completely